# AngularJS: ng-model not updating object, but updates field in object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am working with AngularJS project and I have the following problem. I have a code:

**form.html**:

```
<form>
  <input ng-model="someVariable" type="text"/>
</form>
```

**details.html**:

```
<div ng-include="'form.html'"></div>
{{ someVariable }}
```

**AngularJS Controller for details.html**:

```
angular.module('SomeModule')
  .controller('DetailsController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.someVariable = {};
});
```

With this code someVariable is not displaying, but when I change ng-model to someVariable.someField, and i try to display it... it works! Could anyone explain me why?

Comment: prototypal inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - the `someVariable` is a primitive (Boolean, null, undefined, number, string, symbol (new in ECMAScript 6)). When Angular is searching for a variable to interpolate, if it's not found on the scope it can be looked up the prototypical chain only if that variable is not a primitive, like an object for instance.

`ng-include` creates a new scope, and your variable is a primitive so it is not found.

When you place it under an object, the object is not found on the new child scope created by the `ng-include` but it is searched at the parent scope which is then found and rendered.

For more detailed info - read [Understanding Scopes.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)